# Привязка события на клик Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

пишу простой TODO list на Angular.

У меня есть такой код:

HTML:

```
<button mat-button color="warn" (click)="doneTask(taskIdx)">
            DONE
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

JS:

```
  doneTask(taskIdx: number) {
    
  }
```

И я не могу разобратся как в методе doneTask вызвать изменения задания, должно зачеркнутся и забрать линию если клавиша была нажата еще раз.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать ngClass(https://angdev.ru/guide/directives/ngclass-ngstyle/) и привязать к нему свойство своего объета `[ngClass]={checked:task.completed}`.

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let task of tasks; let taskIdx = index">
        <span mat-line [ngClass]="{checked:task.completed}">{{task.description}}</span>
        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="removeTask(taskIdx)">
            DELETE
        </button>
        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="doneTask(taskIdx)">DONE</button>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Дальше остается в коде только поменять его на нужное значения

```
doneTask(taskIdx: number) {
    this.tasks[taskIdx].completed = true;
}
```

Comment: можете подсказать что не так, пробовал сделать так как вы написали, но текст не перечеркивает [линк](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dtin-tasklist-angular-pprkvc?file=src/app/task-list/task-list.component.html)

Логика удаления и зачеркивания в папке task-list

Comment: @Vadym, все зависит от версии Angular, в частности тег angularjs используется для версия 1.x. У вас же angular просто и для его тег angular. Код будет различатся: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dtin-tasklist-angular-t8doai?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftask-list%2Ftask-list.component.html Подправил код в сообщения под требования.

Comment: @InDevX, учёл Ваше замечание.